# RN: Swipe Back to different Screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

**I am trying to Make the go back swipe go to different screen**

I have the following order of screens `MenuScreen`, `CartScreen` then `PaymentScreen`.

so for example if the user in the `PaymentScreen` and swipe back user should go back to the `CartScreen` but I wanna navigate the user to the  `MenuScreen` NOT TO `CartScreen`

```
useEffect(() => {
    navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', e => {

      e.preventDefault();

      navigation.navigate('MenuScreen');
    });
  }, [navigation]);
```

but I am facing this error:

```
ERROR  RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
```

any clue how to solve this problem? or maybe solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this. Following are the pointers:

- [StackActions Reference](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/) **[PREFERRED]**: Now you can read more about this from the link itself, but precisely, you can use if the navigation is not that complex as it looks. So the task is, `first moving from Menu -> Cart -> Payment` and then when going back `Payment -> Menu`. To do that using this, you simply have to use `StackAction` using `navigation`:

```js
import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

// While going from Menu -> Cart
navigation.navigate('Cart');

// While going from Cart -> Payment (Here is the key)
navigation.dispatch(
  StackActions.replace('Payment')
);
```

Now when you just swipe back, you will see the **Menu Page** only.

**What did we do:** We replaced the `Cart` from the navigation stack, so only pages which were available were, Menu and Payment in the stack. Resulting in going back to Menu. Do not forget to use `navigation.navigate() to go to` Cart`. It will help you.

- [CommonActions Reference](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions) **[NOT SO PREFERRED]**: Now this will completely reset the navigation as per your will, and help you achieve what you want to achieve. Here you don't have to actually worry about what do you use while navigating from `Menu -> Cart`, but we do have to worry about going from `Cart -> Payment`.

**Disadvantage:** While using this, you will lose all the progress you have made in the `Menu` page, which you want to see while coming back from `Payment -> Menu` using `Swipe`, `Android Hard Back button`. Also, it will reset the whole navigation stack, so you are creating a new stack with your means. Hence, **not so preferred**

```js
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

// from Menu -> Cart
navigation.navigate('Cart');

// From Cart -> Payment (Most important) -> Resetting the whole stack
navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    index: 1,
    routes: [
      { name: 'Menu' },
      { name: 'Payment' },
    ]
  })
);
```

Comment: Why not use `navigation.replace('Payment')` instead of StackActions?

Comment: `StackActions` is an object containing methods for generating actions specific to stack-based navigators. And it looks safe as well @Moistbobo

Answer (score -2):

Use `navigation.reset` or `navigation.popToTop()`

```
useEffect(() => navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', e => {

      e.preventDefault();

      navigation.popToTop();
    });
  , [navigation]);
```

Comment: I tried both `navigation.reset ` && `navigation.popToTop()` but it shows the same problem `ERROR  RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.`

Comment: Which @react-navigation do you use?